# Ignoring bad certificates on HTTPS connection in j2me application

Tags: java, ssl, java-me, ssl-certificate

I have appended ";CertificateErrorHandling=warn;HandshakeCommentary=on" after URL in my j2me application but I am getting "Certificate is expired".

Comment: device and server's both date time is proper

Comment: App is working properly in simulator without the appended parameter but gets error in device